# Java How to represent a decimal number in a long

Tags: java

How do I convert a String number: "6542.5699999999997" into a long? Lets say I want to have 8 digit precision in the long so it should look like:

long: 654257000000

And no I don't want to use a BigInt.

Comment: How exact does the precision have to be? Is it always 8 digits after the decimal point, regardless of how many digits are before the decimal point? If so, then you'll probably have to parse the string yourself, since none of the primitive types can handle arbitrary precision.

Comment: Round it then multiply it up. Cast it to a long to truncate the decimals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first multiply, then round like so:

```
long val = (long)(6542.5699999999997 * 100000000 + 0.5);
```

If the number can also be negative, you have to handle that case separately because the `+ 0.5` trick works only for positive values.

Comment: If the input is 6.569 the result must be 657000000 but the output of this code is 656900000

Comment: @RahimDastar I don't get it, why do you want a result of 657000000.

Comment: We should round up 6.569 to 6.57 and then convert it to long. I think!

Comment: @RahimDastar well, the OP said 8 digits precision. So the rounding should be at the 8th decimal.

Comment: Umm I think there is ambiguty. lets ask @Olga

Comment: Yeah the rounding should be on the 8th decimal. So 8 digit precision.

Comment: Note: for negative numbers you need to `- 0.5` ;) +1

Comment: BTW To convert back you need to `/ 1e8` not `* 1e-8`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00000000");
    String longStr = formatter.format(6542.5699999999997).replaceAll("\\D", "");
    Long longVal = Long.parseLong(longStr);
```

Comment: import `java.text.NumberFormat` and `java.text.DecimalFormat`

Comment: This is hugely slow and inefficient. Using mathematical operations will be rather more performant.

Comment: That created quite a few objects, when actually you don't need to create any.